# VW POLO 6n1 1998 Battery Warning Light What it means?

Tags: battery, vw, polo

I turn off my car (Polo 6n1 year 1998)to open my garage then i start the engine and battery warning light didn't turn off.

What's that mean ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [VW](http://www.vwserviceandparts.com/service/volkswagen-dashboard-indicator-lights/), it means you have a charging system problem.

In other words, you need to have the car serviced to have the charging system checked. The problem may be the alternator or ancillary component.

[image]

Source - [Dashboard Indicator Lights](http://www.vwserviceandparts.com/service/volkswagen-dashboard-indicator-lights/)

Comment: Is there a possibility that it could be battery fluid level ? 
otherwise i'm going to take it to have the charging system checked.

Thx

Comment: No, I don't know of any cars that have a fluid level sensor in the battery.

Comment: My experience has been that this is manifested by a failing alternator, most of the time...

Comment: Does alternator could be repaired ?

Comment: The alternator can be repaired or replaced. Typically they are just replaced for cost reasons.

Comment: @CharlieRB thx for the info